# Simple estimation of the critical temperature of water

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, estimation, phase-diagram

I'm trying to develop [fermi estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem) skills and I came up with a question for which I don't even know where to start from. Here goes:

Is it possible to estimate the critical temperature (say in Kelvin degrees) of water in a simple way using [fermi estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem)?

By critical temperature I mean the temperature of the point at the end of the coexistence line of water and vapour. See [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Phase-diag2.svg) plot.

Comment: After having reviewed some of the thermodynamic assumptions for critical point estimation, it doesn't look like it falls exactly into the realm of Fermi estimation. You basically have to put something in that you already know experimentally, like the boiling point and then you have to assume a certain type of interaction between the atoms/molecules of the sample.  I hope someone can give us a Fermi type argument that allows to bypass the usual procedures.

Comment: I can't find a good description of what's going on at the molecular level. It would seem that the molecules are physically constrained to be very close together (like a liquid) but posses so much energy that the itermolecular forces are insignificant.  That's just a guess.

Comment: The microscopic description of the critical point is particularly difficult because it corresponds to an RG fixed point. Fluctuations arise on all scales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimation: I want the two densities of vater and vapour to become approximately equal.

- the density of water is nearly constant
- the vapour pressure (you can derive this from the above mentioned Clausius-Clapeiron-equation) is approximately exponential in $1/T$. This means, that if you increase pressure by a factor, the inverse of the evaporation temperature $1/T$ will increase by some shift.
- the pressure is 100 kPa at 100°C and 611 Pa (if I remember correctly - which is the point of this question here) at the triple point at 0°C, so you have a factor of 150.
- now the corresponding shift in $1/T$: the temperature changed from 275 to 375. I will now calculate in units of 25K. So 1/T changed from 1/11 to 1/15, i.e. from 15/165 to 11/165. It dropped by 4/165.
- the density of air is 1.3 kg*m^-3, so water vapour might be near 1, i.e. 1000 times less than water.
- 1000/150 is nearly 7, so 1000 might be near $150^{1.4}$. Remember, an exponent of 1 corresponds to 4/165 drop in $1/T$.
- let's say the $1/T$ will drop by 5.5/165 more - i.e. the temperature is doubled.
- this means 470°C, which is a bit too much (it should be below 380°C...)

Probably the temperature-dependence of the evaporation heat (and therefore the deviation from the exponential vapour pressure) is the main error; it's hard to say...

Comment: From Wikipedia, $T_c \cong 374°C$. You are off by less than a factor two. Congratulations! Can you please clarify a little, though? I am not used to these calculations and can not follow your reasoning. 'The vapour pressure is exponential' Do you mean $P=A \, e^{B T}$ with $P$ and $T$ the pressure and temperature along the transition line and $A$ and $B$ constants that can be extracted from $P(100) = 100$ and $P(0) = 0.611$? Where does the factor 150 (every 100$K$) come from? Where does the $140K$ difference come from? How is it related to the above ratio of $6 \cong 150^{1/3}$?

Comment: yes, I meant that the $P(T)$ is exponential as you wrote. And exponential means, if you add a shift to $T$, you get a factor in $P$. This factor we get from the two known points; they are 100K apart, and the factor is somewhat more that 150 (since 611 is somewhat less than 2/3 of 1000).

Comment: Since we want a factor of 1000 in the density (qnd therefore approximately in the pressure too), we need to compute $log_{150}(1000)$, to know how many times to go up by 100K. 
150 to the power of what gives 1000? Power 1 gives 150, there is still factor 7 missing. 
$7^3$ is more than 150, so 7 is more than $150^{1/3}$, so factor 7 corresponds to more than a third of 100K as temperature shift. I guessed 40.

Comment: Thanks, I can almost follow you now. I have one last question: Why does the pressure depend on the temperature exponentially? Using the ideal gas law to replace the specific volume ($\Delta v = R T/P$) in the Clausius-Clapeyron relation leads to $dP/dT = L/(RT^2) P$. Then $P(T) \sim \text{e}^{-L/(R T)}$. What am I doing wrong? Are you using $T = 100K + \delta T$ and expanding to first order in $\delta T$, $1/T \cong 1/100 - 1/(100)^2 \delta T$?

Comment: You are right! Thank you, I had always thought, without deriving it, that the pressure is exponential in the temperature. This proves true in practice, but is just wrong conceptually, the pressure is exponential in $1/T$ ... I'll edit the answer!

Comment: Congratulations, the factor is now 1.26 ($=T_{c,estimated}/T_c$). Before it was 1.50.

Comment: Nice work! I had given up on seeing a reasonable answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done a calculation yet, but I would use an extrapolation based on the Clausius-Clapeyron formula:

$$\frac{dP}{dT} = \frac{L}{T\Delta V}$$

You then take any two known thermodynamic quantities of water and water vapor and linearly extrapolate to that point where the difference is zero. A good choice could be the entropy, the entropy of water vapor is easily estimated by treating it as an ideal gas and taking into account the internal degrees of freedom of the H2O molecule. The entropy of water then follows from the latent heat, the way this depends on temperature follows from the well known heat capacity of water.

So, I think it's not that difficult to come up with an estimate with only a blank sheet of paper and a calculator.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand you. What difference should be zero? What depends (approximatively) linearly on what?

Comment: The idea is as follows. Since the two phases become one phase, this means that you can take some arbitrary thermodynamic quantity (density, entropy etc.) compute these as a function of temperature and pressure for both phases and then equate them to each other.

Comment: Ok, I use ideal gas law (for the vapour) to get n = P/RT and set this equal to the density of liquid water. Then I use Clausius-Clapeyron and ideal gas (again) to get n RT = L/(T $\Delta$V). This should provides two equations to solve for T and P. It fails however because at the critical point we have $\Delta$ = L = 0. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use the Van der Waals equation and some estimates of the molecule volume and intermolecular attractive forces. The parameters of the critical point depend on these characteristics, so you need to assess them.

Comment: Water is polar. Does Van der Waals really apply?

Comment: @Floris: I believe so (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force : "The term [the Van der Waals force] includes:
    force between two permanent dipoles (Keesom force)[;]
    force between a permanent dipole and a corresponding induced dipole (Debye force)[;]
    force between two instantaneously induced dipoles (London dispersion force)." See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_constants_%28data_page%29

Comment: Well, thanks for refreshing my memory. I had that completely wrong. Where was my mind coming up with a $r^{-6}$ relationship for Van der Waals force?...

Comment: That is a good idea, but can you do it? Do you know or can you guess (without looking them up!) the actual values of these parameters and can you use them to compute the critical temperature? I know I can't.

Comment: @Steven Mathey: Are you asking if I can estimate these parameters from the first principles? I think it can be done (and it looks like there are a lot of articles on this issue), but I lack time and motivation to do that, sorry.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. The whole idea about Fermi estimations is to be able to use knowledge of quantities that one has memorised to estimate non-trivial quantities. It helps of course to know a lot of things by heart but a lot can also be deduced from physical intuition. So my question is: given a sheet of paper and a pencil (optional) can you come up with a reasonable number for $T_c$?

Comment: @Steven Mathey: No, I cannot. I guess you need to remember the density of liquid water (I remember it, of course) and, probably, the surface tension coefficient of water (I don't remember that).

Comment: @Floris: your memory is correct, the van der Wals interaction goes as $1/r^6$.